# Copying music to an Ipod

Tags: powershell, itunes, powershell-2.0, ipod

I would like to know if there is a way to copy music to an ipod using powershell .

I don’t mind having to install itunes on my pc if it is needed.
I don’t not want to sync my ipod with itunes though or add the files to the itunes library .

The way I copy music now is that I just select the folder with music I want and drag it on to my ipod in itunes. That way it does not add the music to the itunes library .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure it out

```
$IpodName = "type the name of your ipod hear as it apears in itunes"
$SongToCopy = 'c:\tools\test\04.mp3'

#Create a com object to talk to Itunes and List the Librarys
    $iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application
    $LibrarySource = $iTunes.sources

$IpodSource = $LibrarySource.ItemByName($IpodName)

$IpodPlaylists = $IpodSource.Playlists
$IpodPlaylist  = $IpodPlaylists.ItemByName($IpodName)
$IpodTracks    = $IpodPlaylist.Tracks

$IpodTracks.Count

$IpodPlaylist.AddFile($SongToCopy)

$IpodTracks.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe hal rottenberg did something similar here.
http://halr9000.com/article/480

Comment: No that required you ipod to be configured to syn with your pc, I have solved the problem my self. Thanks for the info.